# Laravel 4 - Getting a subset of model attributes

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this laravel model method call:

```
$entry = self::firstOrCreate(array('url' => $url, 'version' => $version));
```

But it has a problem: One of the columns is a TEXT column which could hold really large data I don't need (in this context).

**What do I need**: A way to load-or-create this model without loading the content (TEXT) data.

**Question**: Is there a model method I could use in place of this, or a parameter I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using `firstOrCreate` as you'll need to issue some custom selects. I'd suggest using `firstOrFail`, catch the exception and then create a new model.

```
$payload = compact('url', 'version'); // Build an associative array out of the variables.

try
{
    $entry = Model::where('url', $url)->where('version', $version)->firstOrFail(array_keys($payload));
}
catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    $entry = Model::create($payload);
}
```

Comment: Yep... this was my fallback. Edit your answer since you have a little syntax error (missing brace before `catch`).